# How to extend cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies

This will be setting once user is login to the application

```
$rootScope.user = { username: data.userName, role: data.role, ticket: data.ticket};
$cookieStore.put( 'appCookie', $rootScope.user );
```

After that another api will be invoking to get user details and i have to add firstname and lastname to cookie

something like this

```
$rootScope.user = { username: data.userName, role: data.role, ticket: data.ticket,firstname:data.firstname,lastname:data.lastname};
$cookieStore.put( 'appCookie', $rootScope.user );
```

But i dont want to repeat the code again

Is there any way to extend cookie i mean add firstname and lastname also with existing cookie

I am using Angular js  $cookieStore

Comment: Why not remove the cookie and create a new one with the desired values?

Comment: yes we can do but something like $cookiStore.push('') then i can avoid extra code

Answer (score 1):

```
$rootScope.user = { username: data.userName, role: data.role, ticket: data.ticket};
$cookieStore.put( 'appCookie', $rootScope.user );
```

We can use the angular.extend to achieve this.

```
angular.extend({firstname:data.firstname,lastname:data.lastname}, $rootScope.user);

console.log($rootScope.user);
```